# Swap two lines in a file

Tags: c

I'm writing a program which must swap last line without spaces with the last line in a text file. I must not use extra files. Also the file can be too big for memory, each line of the file also can't be kept in memory fully. I have a function which swaps two lines and it uses function "swap_Next_Lines" which swaps the N-th ant (N+1)-th lines. The offset of the N-th line is passed to the function as a parameter which was got from ftell(). I use a buffer with a fixed size to swap two lines. But it works not right, it mixes all lines in a file. My algorithm: read first k symbols in str1, read next k symbols in str2, then go to beginning and write str2, then str1. Repeat until ftell() returns a value which is bigger or eq to end of 2-nd line. And we repeat it Max_Len / Buf_size times.  Here is the code of the function: (While using GDB I found some bugs and fixed, but sometimes it still works not correct)

```
void swap_Next_Lines(FILE *fin, long base_pos) { 

    int c, i;
    long len1 = 1, len2 = 1, width, tmp_pos, fin_pos, base_pos1;
    char str1[BUF_LEN + 1], str2[BUF_LEN + 1];

    fseek(fin, base_pos, SEEK_SET);

    while (((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) && (c != '\n')) {
        len1 ++;
    }

    while (((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF) && (c != '\n')) {
    len2 ++;
    }
    fin_pos = ftell(fin);

    width = len1 / BUF_LEN;
    width++;

    for(i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        base_pos1 = base_pos;
        fseek(fin, base_pos, SEEK_SET);

        while(1) {

            fseek(fin, base_pos1, SEEK_SET);
            fgets(str1, BUF_LEN + 1, fin);
            tmp_pos = ftell(fin);
            if (tmp_pos >= fin_pos) {
                break;
            }
            fgets(str2, BUF_LEN + 1, fin);

            fseek(fin, base_pos1, SEEK_SET);
            fputs(str2, fin);
            fputs(str1, fin);

            base_pos1 += strlen(str2);

            if (base_pos1 >= fin_pos) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please learn about using markdown for formatting. Taking the [tour], especially [ask] will put you on the right track.

Comment: 'I must not use extra files' - drive nail without using a hammer:(

Comment: If you are being forced to do this horrible thing by your prof/TA, you will need your debugger.  Use a very simple, short file and trace it through, single-stepping, inspecting var values at each step.

Comment: Yes, these are the features of this task. Thank you, it's a good idea to use gdb

Answer (score 1):

Finally found las bug: if len1 mod bufsize = 0, then we dont need to make increment)